# Error Handling in PowerShell Advanced Function

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am trying to add error handling to my script so whoever runs it can see errors in a txt file after. 
I know i can use try, catch to capture errors, but the problem i have is, i have hundreds of lines of script, some Cmdlets which don't have variables to error capture on, **how can i capture the errors for the whole function and export to a txt file to save having to go through each line adding -erroraction stop and put it in a try** block with the catch block having an `out-file` command in it to send to file.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean add -errorvariable to each individual line of code and capture it using +errvar ?

Answer (score 0):

When I need logging, I always just throw something like this in the catch block:

```
 $ErrorName = $Error[0].exception.GetType().fullname
 $ErrorDescription = $Error[0].exception.Message
 "Something went wrong gathering the account names. Cannot continue processing, a fatal error has occurred... `r`n $ErrorName `r`n $ErrorDescription `r`n SCRIPT TERMINATED `r`n " | Out-file -filepath $ErrorLog -append
```

Comment: I have 285 lines of code, how should i try to capture that all?

Comment: @Royston I have scripts that are thousands of lines long, I work in try-catch blocks wherever I have the potential for errors. Another option is the $Error variable catches all errors into an array format, the newest is always [0]. I believe it captures up to 256 errors before overwriting, but that can be modified. Theoretically you could just output the error variable to a log file, but I've never tried it and imagine that it gets messy.